# Gatling Check for logical operation like and & Or

Tags: scala, gatling

How to check value of a parameter either match with value "abc" or "xyz" in gatling. How to check for logical Or & And?

Something like

```
.check(jsonPath($..name).is("abc" || "xyz")

Or

.check(jsonPath($..fname).is("abc") || .check(jsonPath($..lname).is("xyz")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.check(jsonPath("$..name").in("abc" , "xyz")
```

Or

```
.check(jsonPath("$..fname").is("abc"), jsonPath("$..lname").is("xyz"))
```

Comment: Thanks Nikoyay, It's returning false and test is failing if one of the value is not satisfied. Like fname is abc and lname is def then my test case need to pass. It comma in check do logical and or OR?

Answer (score 0):

Gatling Checks leaves a little to be desired. I had a similar problem where I need to check that the Server-header is either Apache or undefined. I found a workaround with using transform like this:

```
.check(header(HttpHeaderNames.Server)
  .transformOption(n => if (n.contains("Apache")) None else n)
  .notExists)
```

Tried to engineer a similar solution for your problem. I think it works, but it seems very hacky:

```
.check(
  jsonPath("$..fname").optional.saveAs(fnameOrLname),
  jsonPath("$..lname").optional.saveAs(fnameOrLname))
.check(status
  .transform((_, s) => s(fnameOrLname).asOption[String]
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  .map(_ => 0))
  .exists)
```